# Which IDE for debugging wireshark?

Tags: linux, debugging, ide, wireshark

I would like to step through some code in wireshark to see how a few things work. I've read some of the Wireshark Build Environment guide but it seems a lot of info is missing. I've never done any programming in linux before so bear with me here.

What is the best IDE to use for debugging Wireshark in Linux? If there isn't one, then how do you debug without an IDE? I've really only developed in Visual Studio so I've been spoiled by it's ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eclipse as a full-fledged IDE with debugging capabilities.  Or you can debug from command line using gdb.  Or you can use DDD, which is a GUI front end for gdb.

Comment: Have you done this before? I was under the impression that getting everything running in eclipse was tricky.

Comment: I have used Eclipse many times, not specifically for wireshark.  It might be 'tricky' to get wireshark to build under eclipse.  But even without that, you can externally build your executable and use Eclipse just to debug it.  Any new tool for you will have a learning curve.